# Representing percentages through getters and setters in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, getter-setter

In my Rails app, I want users to be able to input percentage values as decimals from 0.0 to 100.0. In the database, I want to store them as decimals from 0.00 to 1.00, so that calculations are easier.

I'm currently doing this through getters and setters in the model. But then, when I write derived attributes in the model, they end up using the 0-100 values instead of 0-1, which defeats the purpose of storing it in 0-1 values for easy calculation:

```
# in the model `quote.rb`

def discount=(value)
  write_attribute :discount, value.to_f / 100
end
def discount
  read_attribute(:discount).to_f * 100
end

def final_price
  price * (1 - discount)
  # this generates a wrong value, 
  # because if the user inputs discount as 50 to represent 50%, 
  # the final price will be `price * -49`
end
```

Any ideas on better ways to achieve this?

Comment: Why not store them as integers in the range 0..100 and instead change `final_price` to be `price * (1 - discount / 100.0)`?

Comment: "they end up using the 0-100 values instead of 0-1" - because you told it to, in the getter! Why not just remove the overridden getter and see? Or, better, use `read_attribute(:discount)` directly in `final_price`? Or, even better, have different names for your 0-100 getter/setter and your 0-1 column (discount_percentage and discount_fraction, or something), so that you are able to use both on demand.

Comment: @tadman "Why not store them as integers in the range 0..100" - the rationale given is "to make calculations simpler". Indeed, I can see how it can make some reports _slightly_ simpler. `SELECT price * discount AS adjusted_price ...`.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev That's a valid use case, but I'm not sure it's worth the trouble. I'd write a `discount_factor` method that does the math and use that wherever necessary, leaving it as an integer percentage value.

Comment: @tadman: yep, that's good too

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Generally I like to keep data in the form the user entered it, or expects to be able to view it. Like if they put in inches, keep the raw value they entered and if mm are necessary internally, have a secondary column with normalized values. This avoids problems when your conversion code is screwy, or when you need to switch to a different factor or unit for whatever reason. The user is not really impacted, and their data stays the same.

Comment: @tadman: yah, I remember a particular debugging session, where it turned out I was escaping urls at least twice. Overwriting the source url in the db. So that I couldn't even tell if I escaped it once already. It was baaad. :)

Comment: @tadman I like the idea of keeping the data as the user entered it, your argument makes a lot of sense to me. So that you know what the user entered, no matter if your conversion code changes in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a decimal column (to avoid the [issues with floats and rounding](https://www.noelherrick.com/blog/always-use-decimal-for-money)) to store the raw values (as a percentage) and avoid casting.

You can then simply calculate the net price by using:

```
def final_price
  price * (discount || 100 * 0.01)
end
```

When it comes to dealing with presenting the output to the user you way want to look at the [money gem](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money) as it makes it easier to deal with locales and multiple currencies.

Comment: Going from 0-1 from 0-100 is simply `x * 0.01` - I can't really see the value in storing the converted value in the db as its not complex or expensive to calculate.